# When I Call another sub using an argument, it performs the actions in my original worksheet rather than the newly created worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

In my code, I select items from my workbook and create a new workbook to paste the selected items within.  I then call another sub (Callothers) using an argument to pass along this new workbook such that the remaining code runs in the new workbook.  However, rather than run in the new workbook, the rest of the code occurs in the original.

I have messed with the argument, however I am not reaching a solution.

```
Sub occurences()
'sort

Set oldbook = ActiveWorkbook
    lRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 42).End(xlUp).Row  'Finds the last used row
    Dim coll As New Collection                  'Collections are similar to arrays, but you don't need to declare a size
    For Row = 2 To lRow                         'Loop through each row
        newitem = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Row, 42)  'Grab the contents of the row
        flag = False                                'flag will be false unless we find a match in our collection
        For Each Item In coll                       'loop through our collection
            If Item = newitem Then                  'check for a match
                flag = True                         'if there is a match, set flag
            End If
        Next Item
        If flag = False Then                        'if a match wasn't found,
            coll.Add newitem                        'add the new item to the collection
        End If
    Next Row                                        'now go to the next row and start again

MsgBox (coll.Count)                                 'this tells us how many items are in the collection

For Each Item In coll   'this displays each item in the collection

    Set newbook = Workbooks.Add
    MsgBox ("oldbook a2 = " & oldbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2"))
    With newbook
        Row = 1
        oldbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("a1:ar1").Copy .Sheets("Sheet1").Rows(Str(Row))
        nRow = 2
        For Row = 2 To lRow

            If oldbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Row, 42) = Item Then
                oldbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Rows(Str(Row)).Copy .Sheets("Sheet1").Rows(Str(nRow))
                nRow = nRow + 1
            End If
        Next Row
        fname = Replace(Item, " ", "-")
        fname = fname & ".xlsx"
        MsgBox ("about to call")
        Call CallOthers(newbook)

        .SaveAs Filename:=fname        '("C:\Users\Joshua.Elphee\Desktop\TEST Save\" & fname)
        .Close
    End With

Next Item




End Sub


Sub CallOthers(newbook)

Call Delete_Rows_Based_On_Value(newbook)

Call Delete_Rows_Based_On_Value1(newbook)

End Sub
```

No error message, just performs the actions within the wrong workbook

Comment: May I ask why `Call {Some random procedure}` but not `Call MsgBox`, not `Call .SaveAs`, and not `Call .Close`? The `Call` keyword serves no purpose whatsoever, it's always used inconsistently, and if you think the parentheses in `MsgBox ("something")` are harmless, try adding an icon to that message box.

Comment: It is not clear what your problem even is. It might be that `Delete_Rows_Based_On_Value` and `Delete_Rows_Based_On_Value1` simply ignore the `newbook` parameter, or it might be that they rewrite it with something else which affects everyone because you are passing it `ByRef`. In either case the problem appears to be in these subs and not in the code you have shown.

Comment: `CallOthers` also calls two other subs. It depends on what's going in these subs. Can we see those?

Comment: `If flag = False Then`: a study in proper variable naming and inefficient use of Boolean operators. `if Not itemFound Then` is so much more descriptive than `If Not flag Then`!

Answer (score 1):

You need put more info, but if idea is: You  have 2 workbooks OLDBook and NEWBook , you extract info from OLDBook and put in NEWBook then use "Call Sub OTHER()" and you problem is that instead delete rows in NEWBook delete rows in OLDBook . For you, problem is in your code OTHER but you dont put here (maybe is top secret XD) so you need are explicit sentences like OLDBook.Sheets(1) and NEWBook.close then be sure active workbook you are using like OLDBook.active because when you use .ADD you create a variable as workbooks (collection) that have 2 elements workbook OLDBook and workbook OLDBook ; however if you dont like use this way you also can use public variables on top your module put

```
Public OLDBook as workbook
Public OLDBook as workbook
```

so only you need to use inside your sub()

```
Set OLDBook = ActiveWorkbook
Set NEWBook = new Workbooks
```

or if you have path

```
OLDBook.open "C:\T\"
NEWBook = new Workbook
NEWBook.open
```